# Cant run more than 3 OMXplayer Multiple Streams

Tags: raspberry-pi3, omxplayer

Using a raspberry pi I'm using omxplayer to play 3 screens of IP cameras. When I add the 4th, the screen goes blank and we have to start over.

GPU mem is set to 512. And log says that there is over 700mb GPU remaining.

So what do I do?